# Unable to view web push notification in MacOS Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, onesignal, web-push

- MacOS Ventura
- Chrome v111.x

I am not able to "view" web push notifications in Chrome in my MacBookPro on some websites. Some of the push providers I have tested unsuccessfully are OneSignal and Cleverpush.

I have made sure that MacOS permissions like Settings > Notifications and Settings > Focus are not blocking the notifications (unless I have overlooked something).

Here is how I tested:

1. Go to any of these pages:

   https://cleverpush.com/en/test-notifications/

   https://www.businessinsider.com/guides/tech/chrome-wont-show-notification (OneSignal)

   https://simple-push-demo.vercel.app/
2. Allow web push permission when prompted.
3. For the Cleverpush site, I triggered demo notifications from the web page. I am not receiving any notifications.
4. For the Business Insider site, I opened Chrome Devtools > Application > Service Worker. Then in the Service Worker view, I clicked "Push" to send a test push message. I am not receiving any notifications.
5. For the Vercel app, I triggered demo notifications from the web page. I am able to receive the notifications correctly.

So in the Cleverpush and Business Insider instances, I was not getting any notifications.

Then in Devtools when I go to Application > Background Services > Push Messaging and Background Services > Notifications, I was able to see the correct series of events indicating there were incoming notifications. Please refer to the screenshots.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

FYI, other websites like WhatsApp Web produces notifications correctly in Chrome. I have also tried creating a different user profile for Chrome so that it has a clean state without any extensions installed. No luck.

As a side note, the websites above work fine when tested on Firefox and Safari on the same machine.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed! The culprit was Google Chrome Helper (Alerts) under the MacOS > Notifications settings. That has to be enabled too. Not just Google Chrome.

Comment: this work for me, but with no sound, is there any other thing to do to play default notification sound?

Answer (score 0):

In safari, MacOS already allow notifications, but in chorme or other browser, you need to allow notifications by manual.

Search notifications > find browser > allow notifications.